# http video streaming doesn't work with apple devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

This is my code below that takes get request from client and sends video

```
        const {name} = req.params;
        // console.log(req.headers)
        let range = req.headers.range
        console.log(req.headers);
        
        // if(!range) range = 'bytes=0-'
        if(req.headers.referer !== "https://course-client-nine.vercel.app/"){
            return res.json({message: "No acces from another domain"})
        }
        const myBucket = storage.bucket('coursebuckets');
        const file = myBucket.file(name);
        if(!file){
            return res.json({
                message:"File not found",
                code:401
            })
        }
        const [metadata] = await file.getMetadata();
        const videoSize = metadata.size;
        // const videoSize = fs.statSync('123.mp4').size
        const chunkSize = 1 * 1e+6;
        const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ''));
        let end = Math.min(start+ chunkSize, videoSize - 1);
        let contentLength = end - start + 1;

        const headers = {
            "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
            "Accept-Ranges": 'bytes',
            "Content-Length" : contentLength,
            "Content-Type" : 'video/mp4'
        }

        res.writeHead(206,headers)
            const readStream = file.createReadStream({start, end});
            readStream.pipe(res);
            readStream.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

In chrome it works well but in ios devices it doesn't, no idea and no error, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're properly parsing and using the requested byte range.  So, you respond with a range that is not what Safari asked for.  You appear to be crudely whacking off all non-numeric characters and assuming what's left is the start value and then making your own gigantic chunk size, but that's not the way you're supposed to be parsing the range.  You are not honoring what the client asked for and Safari is pickier than Chrome in that regard.

If you log the request range from the client and then log what you're sending, you will see that they do not match.

From this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/) which is about making streaming work with Safari, here's some range parsing code that gives you the actual requested start and end:

```
if (range) {
    const bytesPrefix = "bytes=";
    if (range.startsWith(bytesPrefix)) {
        const bytesRange = range.substring(bytesPrefix.length);
        const parts = bytesRange.split("-");
        if (parts.length === 2) {
            const rangeStart = parts[0] && parts[0].trim();
            if (rangeStart && rangeStart.length > 0) {
                options.start = start = parseInt(rangeStart);
            }
            const rangeEnd = parts[1] && parts[1].trim();
            if (rangeEnd && rangeEnd.length > 0) {
                options.end = end = parseInt(rangeEnd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```